# Choosing core data or sqlite for large amount of records in IOS

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite, core-data

I am working on creating an Iphone application.  It will contain over 100k+ records and that number might grow with time to even 500k records.  Each record will not be big.  It will contain few fields with text in them.  At some point the application will need to show a large subset in an uitableview.  Might even be 1k records in the view.  I understand that people will not want to scroll through 1k records so i am not sure how i will design it so it will make sense.  Might implement some kind of search which will reload view with every letter a person pressed.
My question is which is better to use for my purpose.  Core data or sqlite.  Which will give me the ability to scroll through the data with out loading 1k dataset into memory and for user be able to quickly scroll through the records.

Thank You in advance!

Yan

Comment: it is not advisable to give a scrolling feature for such large number of records as at any point yo have to fetch them from DB may be on demand or all of them at at a time. Instead you should use filtering method by taking user input. just start fetching/filtering records based on user input event. ideally even on filtering, you should load 25-50 records max. let the user be more specific for the record by inputting some more characters as search string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CoreData and NSFetchedResultsController. It handles large resources efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  This is what i am leaning towards.  I will give it a go and see how it works out.   @samfisher You are right that people will not scroll through a large list of records. I am thinking that people are willing to scroll through thousands of songs on their ipod so people might be interested to scroll through hundreds of records randomly stopping on some.  I am going to see if  it make sense when i actually see it live.

Comment: agree with Oystein.  Use Core Data and NSFetchedResultsController.  Check out the WWDC2010 videos on Core Data, there are some great tips on how to normalize your Core Data model to make searching VERY fast.